# PIA VPN Internet connection problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, internet, vpn

I recently got a PIA VPN subscription and wanted to get the Linux app running on my mini PC with Ubuntu 22.04.
I downloaded the installer from PIA's website and installed it via terminal following the given instructions.
After entering my login credentials I am able to connect to any of the available servers.

Unfortunately, when connected to a VPN server, websites in Firefox are not loading.
Also, updating Ubuntu via terminal doesn't work either because of connection problems. Pinging 8.8.8.8 works, though.

Disconnecting from the VPN server makes everything go back to normal.

From trying to find a solution I learned that this might be some kind of a DNS issue, but I'm honestly a bit lost and would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

P.